# Batch script to list folders but exclude specific folders

Tags: list, batch-file, directory, dir

I want this script to list all folders that contains "deleted" in the folder name but not if they is in a folder called "done".

For exampel: list the folder if it's in `C:\temp` and if it's in `C:\temp\random_folder_name` but not not if it's in `C:\temp\done`

```
dir /s "C:\temp" | findstr "\deleted"
```

short story, exclude all folders named "done" and their content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there.

Findstr /v returns all lines, that do not contain the string

dir /ad will only show directories (Atrribut=Directory)

```
dir /s /ad "C:\temp" | findstr "\deleted" | findstr /v "\done"
```

Comment: Ah - but that would exclude directories and files named `done*` as well, not just `'done'`

Comment: The /ad eliminates filenames - my error. Nevertheless, without a `\` after `\done` this will match `\doneeverything` too. OTOH, using `\done\` will exempt  only `done` directories like `c:\were\all\done\here` BUT won't eliminate directories that end `\done` like `c:\were\not\all\done`. To do that, you'd have to add an extra `|findstr /i /e /v "\done"`.

Comment: to exclude foldernames (use only filenames) dir /a-d.  (see dir /?)

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /s "C:\temp" | findstr "\deleted"|findstr /i /v "\temp\done\"
```

should fit the bill

- or remove the `\temp` part if you want to omit any name which has 'done' as a directory on the path

Comment: it do the job perfect if the "done" folder is in that specific path. I want it to exclude any folder called "done" no matter where in, in this case C:\Temp, it is. 
Sorry if I was unclear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

in lots of cases:

```
dir /b /s /aa <path>
```

Will do the trick. /b for less verbose output, /s for recursive (sub directories) and /aa for only files ready to be archived. This is usually the case for normal created files - it defaults to on!