# How to skip .svn directories and included files in Windows cmd script?

Tags: windows, svn, console, directory, skip

I am currently renaming my Subversion files on a Windows PC in order to solve Umlaut conflicts which cause Subversion on macOS to use another visualization of Umlauts.

But - my current .cmd script doesn't skip the .svn directory and files which makes the script rather slow as the .svn directory contains very many files. I already tried and set the .svn directory attributes to Hidden and System, but the script seems to ignore this although I use the dir command with /A:-H and /A:-S. What am I doing wrong?

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
chcp 1252

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d-h /A:-H /A:-S C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyRepository\*.*') do ( 
  set string=%%~nxi
  set stringnew=%%~nxi

  set stringnew=!stringnew:ä=ae!
  set stringnew=!stringnew:ö=oe!
  set stringnew=!stringnew:ü=ue!
  set stringnew=!stringnew:Ä=Ae!
  set stringnew=!stringnew:Ö=Oe!
  set stringnew=!stringnew:Ü=Ue!
  set stringnew=!stringnew:ß=ss!

  if !string! NEQ !stringnew! (
    echo %%~fi
    rename "%%~fi" "!stringnew!"
  ) 
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe just check those answers how to exclude directories from dir command: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24127017/7225096 https://stackoverflow.com/q/15568541/7225096

Comment: Thank you for that hint, but it seems as if adding something like " | findstr /v \.svn\" doesn't work in my for() loop. I have no idea why not.

Comment: Try this in your for loop: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyRepository\ ^| findstr /v /c:".svn"') do (`

Comment: Excellent, Peska, this works like a charme. I owe you one. :-)